# python3 which module will decomplier .pyc file to .py file?

Tags: python, python-3.6

I try to decompiler the .pyc file back to .py file because I accidentally delete my .py file but I still have .pyc file. So far I download the unpyclib module using pip3 install unpyclib and python3 -m unpyclib.application -Dq path/to/myile.pyc but turn out the unpyclib module is for python 2 version and a few bugs shows on the console like print function missing parentheses and some invalid syntax. So I'm wondering if there is a package for python3 to decompiler the pyc file back to py file?

Comment: https://github.com/rocky/python-uncompyle6

Comment: also, start using a version control system right now